# Linux - mount iso with lowercase directory names

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, iso-image

I'm mounting an iso with:

> mount -o loop -t iso9660 file.iso /directory

what i need to change, to convert all directory and file names to lowercase?

Comment: i don't understand the question.

Comment: when you mount an iso image, all files and directories has uppercase name, like DIRECTORY/FILE.TXT. I need to set them to lowercase, eg: directory/file.txt

Comment: on the iso? you want to remaster the iso? or only on the mounted directory?

Comment: only on mounted directory.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `check=relaxed` and `map=normal` after `-o`
Check the iso9660 section of [mounts manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount).